# Why does x:Key unapply my TabItem Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I am trying to make a custom style for a TabItem Header.  I got it to work by accident.

this fails:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Name="TabHeader3" x:Key="test">
```

but this works

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Name="TabHeader3">
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first Style you have defined is an "explicit" Style, so you must explicitly use it like so:

```
<TabItem Style="{StaticResource test}" />
```

The second Style you have defined is an "implicit" Style. So it will be applied to all TabItem controls below it in the visual/logical tree, or to all TabItem controls if it's defined in the application resources.

Your second Style is equivalent to:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Name="TabHeader3" x:Key="{x:Type TabItem}">
```

So the key is the Type of the object to which it should be applied.

If a TabItem has a Style explicitly defined (like I show above), then any implicit Styles will not be used. Also, if you have two implicit Styles defined, then the closest one wins. So here:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}"> 
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
             <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}"> 
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        ...
        <TabItem ... />
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Blue Style will take precedence over the Red Style.

Finally, you generally don't need to include `x:Name` on your Styles.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the style to a resource dictionary without a key then the style gets applied to all TabItems that are within the scope of the resource dictionary by default. If you add a Key to the style then you need to manually set the Style